# sorting the elements in the list

Tags: python, list, numpy

List A and List B has corresponding elements:

```
A = ['a','c','b']
B = [5,7,9]
```

How to sorting the elements in A (to get A_sorted as below), with the values unchanged in B (get B_sorted as below)?

```
A_sorted = A.sort()

A_sorted = ['a','b','c']
B_sorted = [5,9,7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = ['a','c','b']
B = [5,7,4]

A_sorted, B_sorted = zip(*sorted(zip(A, B))
```

Result:

```
>>> A_sorted
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> B_sorted
(5, 4, 7)
```

Explanation:

```
>>> step_1 = zip(A,B) # creates list of tuples using 
                      # two original lists 
                      # tuples will allow us to keep correspondence 
                      # between A and B   
>>> step_1
[('a', 5), ('c', 7), ('b', 4)]
>>> step_2 = sorted(step_1) # key step: the tuples are sorted by
                            # the first value.                                  
>>> step_2
[('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 7)]
>>> step_3 = zip(*step_2)   # This is just a trick to get back the original
                            # "lists", however they are actually tuples
>>> step_3
[('a', 'b', 'c'), (5, 4, 7)]
```

Comment: thanks. i accept your answer. can you please explain more detail on:zip(*sorted(zip(A, B)) @Akavall

Comment: Try `zip(A, B)`, then `sorted(zip(A, B))`, then see what `zip(('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 7))` looks like, then try to find out what * does to a list, then try to figure out how to `highlight` code in a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

A numpy solution, since the question is tagged with it.  Use `argsort`:

```
s = A.argsort()
A_sorted = A[s]
B_sorted = B[s]
```

How it works:

```
A = np.array(['a', 'c', 'b'])
B = np.array([5, 7, 9])

s = A.argsort()  # returns the _indices_ that would sort A
print s
# array([0, 2, 1])
```

Now you can use `s` to get the sorted lists from `A` or `B`, in the order that would sort `A`:

```
A[s]
# array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
#       dtype='|S1')

B[s]
# array([5, 9, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list.sort()` function does not return a sorted list, but sorts the list in place. Hence, it will return `None`, so you are setting `A_sorted` to `None`.

You have two options here:

- Use `sorted()` where you use `A.sort()`. This will sort the list, but also return the sorted list.
- Don't assign `A.sort()` to anything.

So what I think you're looking for is to create `A_sorted` and `B_sorted` without modifying `A` and `B`. Then here you would use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
A_sorted = sorted(A)
B_sorted = sorted(B)
```

Comment: thanks. though the sorted(B) gives correct result for this question, i want to sort the elements of B according to A since the elements of two lists (A and B) are corresponding to each other. please see the updated question @Haidro